# Does ReSharper require experience before getting it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have about 4-5 years of background in programming some in C# and some in C++. I recently got an internship and have been using C# daily. I am confident in my work, and don't have any problem remembering syntax or anything like that. So I was wondering what you think about getting resharper? I was going to demo it first but I just want to hear other opinions about it. Basically what I'm trying to ask is, should I wait to get it and become more experienced and have more practice with just Visual studios and its built in intellisense and stuff or would it be alright to get it?

Comment: Does anyone know how to revise the file header that gets generated with StyleCop for ReSharper? I have tried to change it in the ReSharper File Header options, but it doesnt seem to change it. any ideas?

Comment: Also is there a way to save your whole resharper configuration so you can load it on another computer. I know you can do that for code styles but not everything.

Comment: Wow ReSharper is amazing hehe =) thanks for the advice guys =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a developer that has been using C# since .net 1.0 days on a daily basis,  I usually likes to keep to the bare bones of an installation, so that if my dev environment is somehow destroyed I can be back and running as fast as possible.  However, I recently did some pairing with another developer which required installing Resharper.  What I found was:

1. I learnt alot about C# features I never new existed.
2. It had a much better test runner than VS.
3. Had much better refactoring tools.

About the only thing I didn't like was that it rearranged some of the default VS keyboard shortcuts, however after a bit of tinkering in the options dialog I was able to turn off the features I didn't need.

I'm missing it now, after the trial.  I'm unfortunately unable to afford the cost of a licence (cash flow problem, not a it isn't worth it problem) at present and can't convince my bosses to get it for me.

Comment: I was wondering if it changed the default VS keybaord shortcuts, do you know which ones it changes?

Comment: Generally the ones I had problem with were shortcuts for navigating around the implmented code, a few around auto completion.  The one I had most trouble with was Ctrl+Click which usually selects the word, with resharper it navigates to the implementation (usually F12).   Wasn't so much a problem as just not what I was used to after 10 years in Visual Studio.

Comment: @Chris: Here's a list of the ReSharper shortcuts. You can set it to VS or IDEA mode, and if there's a conflict, it'll notify you and ask which one you want to use.

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/feature_map.html

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't work without it.  It duplicates a bunch of the Visual Studio stuff, and adds a whole lot more.  It simply improves Visual Studio, and will not impair your learning c# at all.

Comment: I agree 100 percent! If you don't have a lot of extra cash laying around. 200 bucks can be a little steep, but it's well worth the money. In my opinion it's the best productively tool on the market for C# development.

Comment: If you are a pro, it's going to payback $200 in productivity gains very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Make a point of trying out [Refactor Pro and CodeRush](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/) during your research as an alternative to Resharper. Together they're an unstoppable productivity machine. I used them for years when I developed in C# and working without them feels like I'm missing an extra me. :-)

For sure you should look into both products, though. It's not about remembering syntax, it's about reducing the number of coding errors that everyone makes all the time.

Comment: I believe that while Refactor Pro and CodeRush are helpful with C++, but they really can't stand the comparison with ReSharper when it comes to C# (especially C# 3.0). Besides I found Refactor Pro (and the DXCore in general) to be cause huge performance drops, so I wouldn't recommend them at all..

Comment: Good advice, it's always good to check the competition for better tools.

Comment: Good idea, I know a couple guys who use Refactor Pro and CodeRush, and they are very happy.  I've downloaded the demo more than once, but never quite got so far as installing it.

Comment: I agree with doing research on other things to see what else is out there. thanks for the tip =)

Comment: I concur with @emaster, I have noticed a huge performance gain with VS ever since I disabled dxcore

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you from my experience that no matters how solid are your skills ReSharper is quite addictive, and it's a great enhancement for C# programming in VS. In fact the addiction comes from the fact that it can really make you save a lot of time otherwise spent doing tedious tasks and at the same time it'll help you write clean code which turns in less time spent refactoring (which is made faster by ReSharper anyway).
If properly configured, it can be - in my opinion - the most valuable VS addin and I couldn't really see why you should deny yourself access to that :)

Answer (score 1):

Well worth the money, particularly if you can get your company to buy it for you. I theoretically could work without it, but I wouldn't want to.

Answer (score 0):

Resharper is like learning piano chords and then being able to play any song you hear. You can write code the "wrong" way, highlight some of it, do a key combination, and clean it up.

v4.5 makes huge strides in performance as well. Some big solutions would get bogged down, but this one is a lot snappier. It's solid top to bottom.